# MATLAB: How do you add all the first n rows of a matrix within the same column, and save the result to the last row?

Tags: matlab

It was hard to phrase the question, but here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
1 2 3 4
2 1 1 1
2 2 3 1
0 0 0 0
```

and in column one, I add all the value of all of the first three rows and save it to the third and so on, so that it becomes:

```
1 2 3 4
2 1 1 1
2 2 3 1
5 5 7 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `sum`:

```
octave:23> m = [1 2 3 4; 2 1 1 1; 2 2 3 1; 0 0 0 0]
m =

   1   2   3   4
   2   1   1   1
   2   2   3   1
   0   0   0   0

octave:24> m(length(m), :) = sum(m)
m =

   1   2   3   4
   2   1   1   1
   2   2   3   1
   5   5   7   6
```